# Scroll fixed positioned <div> horizontally

Tags: html, css

I am using a `<div>` which is fixed at the screen top. This div contains a menu. The rest of the page can be scrolled vertically and horizontally.

If the user has a small display, he cannot reach all items in the menu, although he can scroll horizontally. If I use `overflow-x` , the `<div>` would get its own scrollbar, which does not look good. I want that page and menu shares the main horizontal scrollbar.

Note: In my case, the width of the page is **always** aligned to the same size as the menu.

**https://jsfiddle.net/8gL16o28/**

---

**HTML**

```
<div id="menu">
    <img src="http://www.widescreen-wallpapers.de/wallpapers/502-sonnenuntergang-1.jpg" height="50" width="3000" />
</div>

<img src="http://i156.photobucket.com/albums/t40/solvaenda/mein1Blumenbild.jpg" height="3000" width="3000" />
```

**CSS**

```
#menu {
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    height:50px
}
body {
    margin-top:50px;
}
```

Comment: Just saying, I hate scrolling horizontally on webpages.

Comment: @jcuenod I mentioned "If the user has a small display". The page is 1100px wide, so "normal" users would probably never have to scroll horizontally. But if someone runs the page in a 700x500 window instead of fullscreen, an important item in the menu will not be visible.

Comment: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/12/guidelines-for-responsive-web-design/

Comment: On small screens, like mobiles, the scrollbar won't be visible. I wouldn't care. apple.com using the same for the menu.

Answer (score 1):

Use position:absolute then.

```
#menu {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    height:50px
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8gL16o28/2/

JS correction:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window ).scroll(function(){
        $("#container").css("top",$("body").scrollTop()) 
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8gL16o28/3/

Comment: Indeed. The menu isn't always on the top then. This is the whole reason why I am using this container. Maybe I need to explain a bit more what I want to do: The website is a large questionnaire with a width of 1100px. The menu will have a back button and a next button. Both alligned left and right of these 1100px. If the window-width is smaller than 1100px, the user can never see the "next" button, and everything is ruined then. But the menu shall be always on the top, so the user can stop the questionnaire at every step (and the page needs to be DAU-safe...

Answer (score 0):

I would add a onscroll event to the BODY tag.  Have the menu div have an overflow of hidden. Then in the onscroll function check the scroll position of the page:

```
left = window.pageXOffset || document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
```

Then you can set the scrollLeft attribute of the div appropriately.